# show/hide slider toggle for any number of IDs

Tags: jquery, html, css

> I looked at [this tutorial at w3schools for a jQuery slider
>   toggler](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_toggle) and wanted to make one for myself. However, my requirement
>   is a little different. I don't want to ***rigidly*** define each **CSS
>   style** and **jQuery function**.

For example, in w3school's implementation, they've used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

but I want to do something of this effect:

```
function toggleX(fid,pid){

var flipvar = document.getElementbyId(fid);
var panelvar = document.getElementbyId(pid);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(flipvar).click(function(){
        $(panelvar).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});

}
```

My requirement is that I should be able to achieve this effect in HTML simply by doing this:

```
<div id="flip" onclick="toggleX('flip','panel');">...</div>
<div id="panel">...</div>
<!-- Similarly for any number of DIVs in same pattern -->
<div id="flip1" onclick="toggleX('flip1','panel1');">...</div>
<div id="panel1">...</div>
```

If it makes you easier to see the thing itself, here is the snippet below. Please look at it and suggest improvements.

```js
function toggleX(fid,pid){
  fid.style.background="#fff";//This is for testing purpose but the color never changes :/
}
//IF I could make that^ function work, I am planning to use the function below by using the id-values I get from onclick event

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
#panel, #flip {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
    border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
    padding: 50px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flip" onclick="toggleX('flip','panel');">Only this one works right now(Click me)</div>
<div id="panel">This slider is working only for THIS div and this slider is getting its style from 'panel' and 'flip' CSS. Can I get those CSS attributes by ID?<br/>(for flip1,panel1,flip2,panel2...and so on?)</div>

<div id="flip2" onclick="toggleX('flip2','panel2');">I want to make this DIV slidable show/hide too!</div>
<div id="panel2">And I want to get CSS style from ID too! :/</div>

<!--
I want this to happen for any number of ids that I make and pass with toggleX function.
-->
```

### Let me finally break down the question once again..

**I want:**

- Slider toggle for many many divs
- Each independent from each other but each using the same central function and deriving its style from the same CSS

**I do not want:**

- **Class-based answer** because [I did read this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3137720/5040900) but that did not answer my question. Neither was it quite what I was looking for. I would prefer an ID-based answer.

  - ...and I must have messed it up because I could not get it to work, as you can see in the snippet below, it works!(although not as desired) in SO, but it [refuses to work in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lancel0t/nce1gcjk/) which worries me about specific dependencies. Will this not work with specific settings or platforms?

    ```js
    $('.toggler').click(function(evt) {
      var $toggler = $(this);
      var $container = $toggler.siblings('.container');

      $container.toggle();
      $toggler.text($container.is(':visible') ? "Hide" : "Show");
      evt.preventDefault();
    });
    ```

    ```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="toggleset">
      <a class="toggler" href="#">Hide</a>
      <div class="container">
        Data to show/hide
      </div>
      <br/>
      <a class="toggler" href="#">Hide</a>
      <div class="container">
        Data to show/hide
      </div>
    </div>
    ```
- **multiple CSS for each div** because I dont know how many DIVs I'll be using for a slider in the future (okay maybe 10 at most but I want clean CSS dammit)
- **multiple functions for multiple IDs** because I'm going to put the jQuery function in my template and then use the div wherever required in my posts and pages, as I mentioned earlier:

like this(*this is my ideal solution*):

```
<div id="flip" onclick="toggleX('flip','panel');">...</div>
<div id="panel">...</div>
<!-- Similarly for any number of DIVs in same pattern -->
<div id="flip1" onclick="toggleX('flip1','panel1');">...</div>
<div id="panel1">...</div>
```

### What kind of solution?

- **Creative answers are entertained** even if they do not meet my above-mentioned specifications. If you can do this with class, do it! I point out ID simply because I believe solving by ID would be effective.
- **Better Practice:** As you can tell, I am a novice at this. If you know some better practice for making toggle sliders for such purposes, I'd heartly appreciate it!
- **Meet me halfway:** If you have been trying to solve this but you also got stuck somewhere, feel free to provide an answer. I'll be trying to solve it on my own meanwhile.

Comment: Too many ids!  Try to make your structure the same for each widget, and locate the elements inside your widget relatively, and figure out why your class-based solution didn't work (it's the right way to do it!)

Comment: That was a completely different example @James . I just wanted to show how that section did not work out for me. I thank you regardless of that because it your fiddle helped me understand  the class-implementation (which was native to my own code) better.

Comment: There's really no difference.  You can use exactly the same technique with this new code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it with [`attribute starts with selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) function,

```
 $("div[id^=flip]").click(function() {
   $(this).next("div[id^=panel]").stop().slideToggle("slow");
 });
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mw50n8rh/3/)

I have answered the question in the way you asked above. But using a common class for this situation is the right move. Since elements with id will create unnecessary references in the global scope for named access.

```
 $("div.flipClass").click(function() {
   $(this).next("div.panelClass").stop().slideToggle("slow");
 });
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mw50n8rh/5/)

Comment: This has all of the requirements so far, and it's neat, I like the proper usage of different jquery selectors, well done

Comment: excellent! **Exactly** what I wanted. I am impressed you could do it with such a short code. +1 and marked ^_^

Answer (score 1):

This is all what you want I think.

```css
[id^=panel],
[id^=flip] {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

[id^=panel] {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function toggleX(pid) {
    $("#" + pid).slideToggle("slow");
  }
</script>
<div id="flip1" onclick="toggleX('panel1');">Only this one works right now(Click me)</div>
<div id="panel1">This slider is working only for THIS div and this slider is getting its style from 'panel' and 'flip' CSS. Can I get those CSS attributes by ID?
  <br/>(for flip1,panel1,flip2,panel2...and so on?)</div>
<div id="flip2" onclick="toggleX('panel2');">I want to make this DIV slidable show/hide too!</div>
<div id="panel2">And I want to get CSS style from ID too! :/</div>
```

Comment: I am giving this a +1 for going with the CSS approach. Again, as with other  answers, this is helpful for learning :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Solution for id
function toggleX(fid,pid){
$('#'+pid).slideToggle("slow");
}

//I would do it like this  
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flip">...</div>
    <div class="panel">...</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flip">...</div>
    <div class="panel">...</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.flip').click(function() {
        $('.panel', $(this).closest('.wrapper')).slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why is it down voted ? (Please leave comment when you down vote)

Comment: I am sorry, I wouldn't know. I did not downvote this. Thanks for your answer anyways. It helped me understand something(I was also trying the '#'+ method before and now I know how that way goes. I'll +1 for that(because this is helpful for learners)

Answer (score 0):

Converting my comment.

A few observations:

- Do NOT have a document.ready inside another function.
- It is confusing if you mix `$("#id")` and `document.getElementbyId("id")`
- W3Schools is NOT a great resource - use MDN or other tutorials

It looks to me you can use a class anyway and use .next() to get at the div you want to flip.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".flip").on("click", function() {
    $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.panel { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip">Show panel1</div>
<div class="panel">Panel 1</div>
<div class="flip">Show panel2</div>
<div class="panel">Panel 2</div>
<div class="flip">Show panel3</div>
<div class="panel">Panel 3</div>
<div class="flip">Show panel4</div>
<div class="panel">Panel 4</div>
```